# Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, onload, innerhtml

Why do I get an error or Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null?
I thought I understood innerHTML and had it working before.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type ="text/javascript">
    what();
    function what(){
        document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = 'hi';
    };
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="hello"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 246, accepted):

You have to place the `hello` div before the script, so that it exists when the script is loaded.

Comment: If you use window.onload = function name(){}  it doesn't matter if the div is before or after.

Comment: Crispy solution. But  I am getting the error still. In chrome/fedora 25/apache

Answer (score 77):

Let us first try to understand the root cause as to why it is happening in first place.

> Why do I get an error or Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property
> 'innerHTML' of null?

The browser always loads the entire HTML DOM from top to bottom. Any JavaScript code written inside the `script` tags (present in `head` section of your HTML file) gets executed by the browser rendering engine even before your whole DOM (various HTML element tags present within body tag) is loaded.  The scripts present in `head` tag are trying to access an element having id `hello` even before it has actually been rendered in the DOM. So obviously, JavaScript failed to see the element and hence you end up seeing the null reference error.

> How can you make it work as before?

You want to show the **hi** message on the page as soon as the user lands on your page for the first time. So you need to hook up your code at a point when you are completely sure of the fact that DOM is fully loaded and the `hello` id element is accessible/available. It is achievable in two ways:

1. **Reorder your scripts**: This way your scripts get fired only after the DOM containing your `hello` id element is already loaded. You can achieve it by simply moving the script tag after all the DOM elements i.e. at the bottom where `body` tag is ending. Since rendering happens from top to bottom so your scripts get executed in the end and you face no error.

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html>
       <head>
           <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
           <title>Untitled Document</title>
       </head>
       
       <body>
           <div id="hello"></div>
           <script type ="text/javascript">
               what();
               function what(){
                   document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = 'hi';
               };
           </script>
       </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. **Use event hooking**: Browser's rendering engine provides an event based hook through `window.onload` event which gives you the hint that browser has finished loading the DOM. So by the time when this event gets fired, you can be rest assured that your element with id `hello` already loaded in the DOM and any JavaScript fired thereafter which tries to access this element will not fail. So you do something like below code snippet. Please note that in this case, *your script works even though it is present at the top of your HTML document inside the `head` tag*.

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html>
       <head>
           <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
           <title>Untitled Document</title>
           <script type ="text/javascript">
               window.onload = function() {
                   what();
                   function what(){
                       document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = 'hi';
                   };
               }
           </script>
       </head> 
       <body>
           <div id="hello"></div>
       </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: Good stuff, but i'd add, I don't think the function that does document.getElementById(..).innerHTML . needs to be put within the onload. As that can load before the DOM loads and there's no error. Only its call needs to be.https://jsfiddle.net/fbz6wLpd/8/

Comment: That's was perfect solution you solved my issue, I tried to attach other code to HTML5 game and I was getting `null` for my query until i used your code and success.

Answer (score 41):

You could tell javascript to perform the action "onload"...  Try with this:

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
window.onload = function what(){
document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = 'hi';
};
</script>
```

Comment: the error is persisting even after the window.onload thing

Answer (score 14):

Just put your JS in `window.onload`

```
window.onload = function() {

        what();

        function what() {
            document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = 'hi';
        };

    }
```

Comment: i've put the function in window.onload like you have shown, but the error persists

Answer (score 13):

The JavaScript part needs to run once the page is loaded, therefore it is advised to place JavaScript script at the end of the body tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Example</title>

</head>
<body>
<div id="hello"></div>
<script type ="text/javascript">
    what();
    function what(){
        document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = 'hi';
    };
</script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Will You Please Stop Capitalising Every Word You Type?

Answer (score 7):

Javascript looks good. Try to run it after the the div has loaded. Try to run only when the document is ready. `$(document).ready` in jquery.

Comment: also type attribute in script tags are obsolete.

Comment: and importing jquery to solve this is overkill unless you plan to use it for this project here on out. `window.onload` might suffice but there are other events available as well. Ref to MDN on `window`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

Answer (score 5):

Here Is my snippet try  it. I hope  it will helpfull for u.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  
<div id="hello"></div>
  
<script type ="text/javascript">
    what();
    function what(){
        document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = 'hi';
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Example</title>

</head>
<body>
<div id="hello"></div>
<script type ="text/javascript">
    what();
    function what(){
        document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = '<p>hi</p>';
    };
</script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but may I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 4):

You could try using the setTimeout method to make sure your html loads first.

Answer (score 3):

The root cause is: **HTML on a page have to loaded before javascript code**. 
Resolving in 2 ways:

1) Allow HTML load before the js code.

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function what(){
        document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = 'hi';
    }
</script>

//or set time out like this:
<script type ="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function(){
       what();
       function what(){
          document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = 'hi';
       };
    }, 50);
    //NOTE: 50 is milisecond.
</script>
```

2) Move js code under HTML code

```
<div id="hello"></div>
<script type ="text/javascript">
    what();
    function what(){
        document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = 'hi';
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="hello"></div>
<script type ="text/javascript">
    what();
    function what(){
        document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = 'hi';
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: problem  is  fist html  div loaded ..than java script function calling  now it work...

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem and it turns out that the null error was because I had not saved the html I was working with.

If the element referred to has not been saved once the page is loaded is 'null', because the document does not contain it at the time of load. Using window.onload also helps debugging.

I hope this was useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

This error can appear even if you load your script after the html render is finished. In this given example your code

```
<div id="hello"></div>
```

has no value inside the div. So the error is raised, because there is no value to change inside. It should have been

```
<div id="hello">Some random text to change</div>
```

then.

Answer (score 1):

The error is self-explaining it is not getting the HTML tag in which You want to set the Data So make tag available to JS then only You can set Data to that.

Answer (score 1):

No doubt, most of the answers here are correct, but you can also do this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function what() {
   document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = 'hi';  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `div` into `p`. Technically innerHTML means it is inside the `<??? id=""></???>` part.

Change:

```
<div id="hello"></div>
```

into

```
<p id="hello"></p>
```

Doing:

```
document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = 'hi';
```

will turn

```
<div id="hello"></div> into this <div id="hello">hi</div>
```

which actually does not make sense.

You can  also try to change:

```
document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = 'hi';
```

into this

```
document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML='<p> hi </p> ';
```

to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

**Add jquery into `< head>`**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Use $document.ready()**   *: the code can be in `< head>` or in a separate file like main.js*

1) using js in same file (add this in the `< head>`):

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
function what(){
    document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = 'hi';
};
});
</script>
```

2) using some other file like main.js (add this in the `< head>`):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

and add the code in main.js file :)

Answer (score 0):

There are different possible cause as discussed would just like to add this for someone who might have the same issue as mine.

In my case I had a missing close div as shown below

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html>
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <title>Untitled Document</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div> //I am an open div
    <div id="hello"></div>
   <script type ="text/javascript">
       what();
       function what(){
          document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = 'hi';
       };
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Missing a close div can result in disorganization of the transversal from child to parent or parent to child hence resulting in an error when you try to access an element in the DOM

Comment: Please answer as per OPs example.

Comment: @mishsx the reason for my reply: I had the exact same error and when I searched I saw everyone's fixes but wasn't the fix in my own case, asking the same question would be duplicating, I felt someone else might be in the exact same situation too and I decided to post my own error and fix as a repl... as you can see it is clearly stated on the reply hence it will be helpful to those in the exact same situation and yet clear to others that this isn't the fix to the error in the question. If this isn't ok, kindly advice on how I should make an alternative error and fix known without duplicating

Answer (score 0):

Let the DOM load. To do something in the DOM you have to Load it first. In your case You have to load the `<div>` tag first. then you have something to modify. if you load the js first then that function is looking your `HTML` to do what you asked to do, but when that time your `HTML` is loading and your function cant find the `HTML`. So you can put the script in the bottom of the page. inside `<body>` tag then the function can access the `<div>` Because DOM is already loaded the time you hit the script.

Answer (score 0):

> I have moved my <**script**> tag below the <**body**> tag. Let’s try

```
<body>
    <p>The time is <span id="time"></span>.</p>
</body>

<script>
// Allways keep script at end for date and time object //

    var d = new Date();

    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = d;
    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when using Django template tags on an if-check to see if there was a value available for a field - if no value I removed everything associated with the value from the page to keep things neat The only problem was the content I removed included the div and id I was trying to work with! If there was a value present there was no issue as the div that contained the id I was working with was present. If there was no value I received the error. Once it hit me that's what was going on then easy fix to just add the div in there if the if-check is false.

Before

```
{% if model.value %}
<div id='my-id'>{{model.value}}</div>
{% endif %}
```

After

```
{% if model.value %}
<div>{{model.value}}</div>
{% else %}
<div id='my-id'></div>
{% endif %}
```