# Javascript: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at HTMLButtonElement.but.onclick (

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get it so that each time the randomise button is hit, a new div's inner HTML is displayed - however I get the error message in the Javascript console 'cannot set property'. Can somebody explain what this means and what I'm doing to cause it?

```
<h1>Test</h1>

<div id="quote1">this is quote number 1</div>

<p id="quote 2">this is quote number 2</p>

<div id="quote 3">this is quote number 3</div>

<button id="button1">Randomise</button>



<script type="text/javascript">

var but = document.getElementById('button1');
but.onclick = function() {
document.getElementById("quote1").innerHTML = "hi";
document.getElementById("quote2").innerHTML =  "ho";

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239430/cannot-set-property-innerhtml-of-null)

Answer (score 0):

That because the id is `quote 2` and not `quote2` i.e you have extra space in between `quote 2` and `quote 3`

Change to

```
<p id="quote2">this is quote number 2</p>
```

```html
<h1>Test</h1>

<div id="quote1">this is quote number 1</div>

<p id="quote2">this is quote number 2</p>

<div id="quote3">this is quote number 3</div>

<button id="button1">Randomise</button>



<script type="text/javascript">

var but = document.getElementById('button1');
but.onclick = function() {
document.getElementById("quote1").innerHTML = "hi";
document.getElementById("quote2").innerHTML =  "ho";

} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

your id is set to "quote 2" but you're referencing it as "quote2". It displays "cannot set property" because it cannot find any element referenced as "quote2". Change your id to "quote2". And same for "quote3"
This should work

```html
<h1>Test</h1>

<div id="quote1">this is quote number 1</div>

<p id="quote2">this is quote number 2</p>

<div id="quote3">this is quote number 3</div>

<button id="button1">Randomise</button>



<script type="text/javascript">

    var but = document.getElementById('button1');
    but.onclick = function() {
            document.getElementById("quote1").innerHTML = "hi";
            document.getElementById("quote2").innerHTML =  "ho";

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you! How I overlooked that I do not know ahh.

Comment: No problem. Just follow the flow of your code next time.