# Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null??

Tags: javascript, html

Why do I get this error in javascript:
Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

My code:

```
<asp:Literal ID="topLinkArticleOut" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
<button type="button" id="deleteTopLinkArticle" name="deleteTopLinkArticle" 
onclick="ChangeText()" class="btn red" style="float: right;">Delete</button>

function ChangeText() 
{
document.getElementById("topLinkArticleOut").innerHTML = "";
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239430/cannot-set-property-innerhtml-of-null)

Comment: view-source see what the real id is

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know an `<asp:Literal` will just output text so there won't actually be a HTML element with an ID for you to target. If you use label it will output a HTML element. However I am not sure what that asp code it doing, because it would be outputting nothing and with label it would output an empty HTML element anyway.

```
<asp:Label ID="topLinkArticleOut" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```