# I'm getting "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting the error "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null" with this :

```
<div id="refresh">Loading ...</div>
<script src="test/js/refresh.js"></script>
```

refresh.js :

```
$("#refresh").load("test/ajax/refresh.php");
```

Why ?

PS: Screenshot of the code, if needed : http://prntscr.com/fpvjuf

And the code : https://hastebin.com/ziqinoyulo.xml

Comment: that means you are processing the div before you retrieve it from the document.You sure that the script is running after the page has loaded?

Comment: @AbhishekRanjan Yes. http://prntscr.com/fpvjuf

Comment: Please link the full refresh.js?

Comment: @AbhishekRanjan Done

Comment: @Matt debugging code from a screenshot is .....can't say it

Comment: @Amorris That is all.

Comment: Can you share your refresh.php file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239430/cannot-set-property-innerhtml-of-null?rq=1

Comment: @AbhishekRanjan Oh sorry, look now.

Comment: In the code you linked, there is no div with the Id of "refresh".

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript code may be running before the page has loaded. Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#refresh").load("test/ajax/refresh.php");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My refresh.php file was returning document.getElementById("refesh").innerHTML = "Test";

refesh and not refresh, sorry.

Comment: do you mean this is just a typo issue?

Comment: @shaochuancs Yes