# How to insert a php array with innerHTML in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I would like to be able to insert html code from javascript, which inserts php code that contains an array. What I do is get in the variable $ teams an array of teams. And then I go through the array with a foreach to set the values ​​in the select options

I have done the following but it does not work.

```
document.getElementById('selectTeam').innerHTML = '<select class="form-control"><?php $teams = ControllerTeam::ctrTeam(); foreach ($teams as $key => $value) { echo '<option value="'.$value["id"].'">'.$value["name"].'</option>';}?></select>';
```

Comment: what does "does not work" mean? it does not change the content? the content it changes to is not correct?

Comment: instead of the PHP code, try to hardcode an `<option value="123">Aha</option>` and see if that works

Comment: @cornel.raiu The console throws the following error: **login.js: 78 Uncaught TypeError: Can not set property 'innerHTML' of null**. I have tried with a simpler example and it works. I think the problem is the combination of double and single quotes in the php part inside the innerHTML

Comment: does this work? `document.getElementById('selectTeam').innerHTML = 
'<select class="form-control"><option value="123">Aha</option></select>';`

Comment: @cornel.raiu Yes. Now the simplest examples work. For now the problem is in the php part inside the inner, I think I'm sure it's because of the double and single quotes

Comment: is it possible that when you do it using PHP the `selectTeam` element is not loaded BEFORE the JS part? Are you doing the JS part onLoad or smth? Check this example with the exact same error you get: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239430/cannot-set-property-innerhtml-of-null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239430/cannot-set-property-innerhtml-of-null)

Comment: The error is not related to the content you are trying to add but to the fact that JS does not find this: `document.getElementById('selectTeam')` since the JS loads before the content in your case hence it is null. So, JS sees it like: `(null).innerHTML='bla bla'` which is not valid

Comment: @cornel.raiu Yes. Already that error does not appear. What happens now is that, when printing the html that I indicate in innerHTML, the php part appears in the form of a comment.

Comment: I will add an answer

Comment: @cornel.raiu thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem is that, probably, the content is loaded after the JS so the selector returns null hence the error in the OP code.
[Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239430/cannot-set-property-innerhtml-of-null)

That means, you should only execute the JS code on `window.load` or any other similar event that ensures the fact that the HTML is loaded before trying to execute.

Now, for the other issue in the comments, if you rewrite the PHP code like this :

```
<?php
$teams = ControllerTeam::ctrTeam();

$options_html = '';
foreach ($teams as $key => $value) { 
    $options_html .= '<option value="' . $value["id"] . '">' . $value["name"] . '</option>';
}?>
```

And in the JS - make sure it loads on `window.load` or similar -

```
document.getElementById('selectTeam').innerHTML = 
    '<select class="form-control"><?php echo $options_html ?></select>';
```

This makes the code more readable and helps you debug easier.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)

Comment: Glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your code. Please change it to:

```
document.getElementById('selectTeam').innerHTML = '<select class="form-control"><?php
$teams = ControllerTeam::ctrTeam();
foreach ($teams as $key => $value) {
    echo '<option value="' . $value["id"] . '">' . $value["name"] . '</option>';
}
?></select>';
```

Comment: The code you have given me also contains a typing error. I have put it in my project and it gives error

Comment: I think the problem is double and single quotes

Comment: why don't you prepare the options string outside the JS and only add a variable there. The code will be much more readable.